# runtime error: signed integer overflow: 99998 * 100000 cannot be represented in type 'int' [solution.c]

Tags: c, overflow

Trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/k-concatenation-maximum-sum/submissions/,  I still got integer overflow when the data type is `long`

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int sum(int *nums, int numSize) {
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numSize; ++i)
        ans += nums[i];
    return ans;
}

int KandaneAlgo(int *nums, int numSize) {
    int i, max_overall_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numSize; ++i) {
        max_ending_here += nums[i];
        if (max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0;
        if (max_overall_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_overall_so_far = max_ending_here;
    }
    return max_overall_so_far;
}

int kConcatenationMaxSum(int *arr, int arrSize, int k) {
    int mod = pow(10, 9) + 7;
    int ans;
    if (k > 1) {
        long tem = (k - 2) * max(sum(arr, arrSize), 0);
        int t1 = tem % mod;
        printf("%ld, %d, %d \n", tem, t1, mod);
        int arr2[2 * arrSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * arrSize; ++i)
            arr2[i] = arr[i - i / arrSize * arrSize];
        ans = (int)t1 +  KandaneAlgo(arr2, 2 * arrSize) % mod;
    } else {
        ans = KandaneAlgo(arr, arrSize) % mod;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    int arr[10] = { [0 ... 9] = 10000 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    int tot = kConcatenationMaxSum(arr, 10, 100000);
    printf("%d \n", tot);
    return 0;
}
```

I locally debug with `lldb` and can see the output message of variable `tem` is wrong indeed, it should be `9999800000`.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: @RetiredNinja `long tem = (k - 2) * max(sum(arr, arrSize), 0);`

Comment: `k - 2` is an int, `max` returns an int. Doesn't matter what you're assigning to, if you need the math done with longs then one or both sides must be a long or cast to one.

Comment: Also long isn't necessarily 8 bytes. Depends on system. Use long long to be on the safe side. Or take the step up to professionalism and start using stdint.h instead of the primitive types.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Brilliant, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `9999800000` is larger than what can be stored in 32 bits. `long` only provides a minimum size guarantee of `32` bits. If you use `long long` for all the operands and result variable in the expression, it evaluates to the correct value. `long long` provides a minimum guarantee of 64 bits.
Check this for more details - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Main_types

The following snippet worked for me:

```cpp
long long tem = (long long)(k-2) * (long long)max(sum(arr, arrSize), 0);
```

Not sure about the rest of the algorithm, but this puts the correct value into `tem`.